# An exercise about sum-product estimate

Tags: co.combinatorics, fourier-analysis, additive-combinatorics, sumsets

I am struggling with 1.11 exercise from the George Shakan "Discrete Fourier Transform".

---

Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ be any set not containing zero with $|A|>\sqrt2q^{5/8}$. Show that:
$$(A+A).(A+A)+A.A+A.A = \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$$
with
$$A+B=\{a+b: a\in A, b \in B\}$$
and
$$A.B=\{ab: a\in A, b \in B\}$$

---

My main idea is prove that
$$|(A+A).(A+A)+A.A+A.A| \geq q$$
I tried with Garaev's Theorem:

> Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ be any nonempty set not containing zero. Then
> $$\text{max}\{|A+A|,|A.A|\}\geq\text{min}\{\frac{\sqrt{q|A|}}{\sqrt2},\frac{|A|^2}{2\sqrt{q}}\}$$

So I'm thinking about two cases:
$|A+A| = \text{max}\{|A+A|,|A.A|\}$ and $|A.A| = \text{max}\{|A+A|,|A.A|\}$
With each, I estimate one part of the left hand side.
For example, with $|A+A| = \text{max}\{|A+A|,|A.A|\}$, I will estimate $|(A+A).(A+A)|$ and try to prove that $|(A+A).(A+A)| \geq q$
Using Garaev's, in this case I have
$$|A+A|\geq\text{min}\{\frac{\sqrt{q|A|}}{\sqrt2},\frac{|A|^2}{2\sqrt{q}}\}$$
Since $|A|>\sqrt2q^{5/8}$ as condition, then
$$|A+A|\geq\text{min}\{\frac{q^{13/16}}{2^{1/4}},q^{3/4}\}$$
With $q \geq 16, q^{3/4}$ is smaller, so I use it as min here, because the other case is finite.
But then, using the same techniques as the author, I can only prove that $|(A+A).(A+A)| \geq \frac{q}{2}$, which is not large enough and I can't estimate the rest part, too.
I'm wondering if my way of proving this is true or not. Hopefully, someone can help. Thanks in advance!

---

I wrote down my proof here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cnHfJDlO3eYdskxoFb_sLytlhZSsybQg/view?usp=sharing
And this is George Shakan's paper:
https://gshakan.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/discretefouriertransform1.pdf

Comment: have you tried this? let $ B = A+A, C = A.A$ and set $b:= |B|,c:= |C|$. by 1.10 we have $bc \ge \min\{q|A|/2, |A|^4/4q\}$. now let $f(b)$ be a lower bound for $|B.B|$ when $|B|\ge b$. similarly let $g(c)$ be a lower bound for $|C+C|$ when $|C|\ge c$. by Cauchy-Davenport it suffices to show $f(b)+g(c)\ge q$ (given the lower bound on $bc$).

Comment: actually looking at your argument, $q/2$ seems to be a rather weak lower bound given the inequality. shouldn’t you be able to deduce $|(A+A).(A+A)|\ge q-q^{3/4}$?

Comment: @ZachHunter Thanks! I didn't think about using Cauchy-Davenport to compare $|B.B + C + C|$ with $|B.B| + |C+C|$, so I had to split it into two cases. I will try this way, hope it will work.

Comment: @ZachHunter i'm wondering which part of my argument make the result be a weak lower bound? Is there any better set of solutions S while double-counting is unnecessary?

Comment: literally just looking at the final two lines. if you have that $|B.B| + q^{1/4}\sqrt{|B.B|} -q > 0$, then $|B.B|  > q- q^{3/4}$ (since $|sqrt{|B.B|}\le q$ always holds). and this is considerably better than just saying it has size $q/2$.

Comment: @ZachHunter Ah it's my bad, I focused on solving a quadratic equation. Anyway, I found a way to solve this. Thanks for your suggestions, it helped me a lot!